# typescript: validate function argument based on callback return type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I'm trying to type a function witch run a callback for each array item and extend that item with a new properties:

```js
interface Row {
    a: number
}
export function extender<
  Data extends Row[],
  T extends object,
  Props extends keyof T
  >(data: Data, extend: (row: Row) => T, newProp?: Props): (T & Row)[] {
      return data.map(row => ({
          ...row,
          ...extend(row)
      }))
}
```

This draft seems to be working when I call

```js
extender([{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }], () => ({ once: 1, more: 2 }), 'once')
```

But once I trying to use `row` argument in `extend` callback, I get an error `Argument of type '"once"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'.`:

```js
// TS_ERROR: Argument of type '"once"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'.
extender([{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }], (row) => ({ once: 1, more: row.a * 2 }), 'once')
```

What am I missed?

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

In your example, `T` is constrained by `object` (which actually represents [all non-primitives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type)). The type of "any plain object" can be represented as `Record<PropertyKey, any>` (which uses the type utility [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)). `PropertyKey` is an alias for `string | number | symbol`, so this type means "any object with keys which are strings, numbers, and/or symbols, with values at those properties that can be any type".

By simply replacing that constraint, your code should compile without a diagnostic error.

---

### More

The current return type of your function has some loss of type information if the input array has members which aren't *exactly* the `Row` type (rather, they extend it), and it doesn't acknowledge the notion that `T` could overwrite the type of property `a` during the process of object merging in the map operation. [Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) can help you preserve this kind of type information, and even preserve things like the length of an input array with a specifically-defined number of elements (a tuple). Consider the following example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQwJYDsDyAjAVhAxsKAXigCU8B7AJwBMAeGS8yS0AaQhABooEUQA+ANwAoUJCgBZAK7AEGOBFoAVKBAAewCCmoBnWIlSYc+fkSgBvKAFpKEBNXIo4IKAG1WUVFADWHcgDMoJQBdAC4g92CoAF8RUXBoAFENLWoIaiUpMAVaAEFVFO09W3tHZ31kdGw8YFdg7hV1TSKKw2qTM3NhKGsShycXVwBJbXVPFB8-QNywyRk5HLQAWyRgPOHRtXrJkACg-lMAMjnZeUUlIWFo4XjxEnIAd06ecJQpJYwIShi49TAqAj+KQofBIRwFZppb60bpQAAiCFkENSxTs-XK9wedU4sMahV0rSqxmAOJ6DCYyJavl2gSUOP4AApqIiEOEEbJuE1UuEGYwHmyWa43h8vsEAJREUx0qAoCAPclgAD84QVYvCyUh6Uy2UU7IQDVMXR6tmAUkoE2ZsgAdEsEGBeY9JVAGZYrW6+dw3VaudoHQ8JdExRKEHpgd4UI8JiGoBrUlqsjk9QaRNdhLhHDoCD60tQAIxmbNfBmw1yWVlQfPRbhl8IAJhi9VhDIlhFMLqgjlwEHCue4Syo3ag9cDpKgAHJOxAxzixYIoAB6eekCg0WhjhBjqAAH3H-dsm53E5BU+4ws+lH4dRu6ZQmcpOfrxELlGLPVLLwrMWrH+HjZ6fpbNtLEnHs+wHcI+StBAoAAKiHGIxVHI8u2nYRZwXJcyHTVd1wPXcBzw5CTxld5z0vYJrwzAhXFhCBa3IAAGbhF2XbC6Fw7d8P3TiiOnEiRQvTjgTSfxUHSWj6N7DDWKodiNx4vcpx4yc+LPL5TB3YSIFE2VqAk8ha2YzCVzkwjFMIlTT1I9ShNGHTxJ6OjyAAZiMmScPkw9zOU49VOswTNLssS9Mc+iABY3Kw2S108rilMPSz+LI2yROC2EWIgYBcC9YQoiffF0lrOJhBY7UFCgbDbHwWUdB0UJKNvLMCuoZyCwKl8SxrCtuAwHsvwsH8errfqutcqBeqgVroiiaNXCijzCIwPyBP4bh5tMnilqsla1pMmLFuWsi-2dPlAOdLqxwACyQPiQO6qBFIgx4oNg+CR1hXiZznec4JonouszShUAAcxiKBjnWtcloUgifJQ7ayNHAHgCBlBQeicH3PY6GvNhhLfIR9SkY-QGQbBiG9rHHG4osgmkqJ3LYPnG4WIAOXITQoGAS7oAANwQOApAgPRES5nmuYTaBUDSNRhZ4WwZQ5qB-maYAkAF8otPs6h6pvO8-tUZzGLc5HUfRzHIapsy8fHRK1IvWijakljTbJjGKbYqHre4-H4fph3HKNwzpNdtHyaxr2YZ9226ft-hHZc5i4KUa69C+RhviQNO1EgfAHKgAA-AvcUlrmEnHVwvWCTc9gUNHufHZzN0u6MI1UBQli0AhRelsYxybq0GVrMKAE5nIlGDmby+90mckQgA)

```ts
type PlainObject = Record<PropertyKey, any>;
type Mutable<T extends PlainObject> = { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

type ExtendedTuple<A extends readonly PlainObject[], T extends PlainObject> = {
  -readonly [Index in keyof A]: Mutable<Omit<A[Index], keyof T>> & Mutable<T>;
}

type Row = { a: number };

export function extender <
  Data extends readonly Row[],
  T extends PlainObject,
  Prop extends keyof T,
>(data: Data, extend: (row: Data[number]) => T, newProp?: Prop): ExtendedTuple<Data, T> {
  return data.map(row => ({ ...row, ...extend(row) })) as unknown as ExtendedTuple<Data, T>;
}

const extended1 = extender(
  [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }],
  () => ({ once: 1, more: 2 }),
  'once',
); // Record<'a' | 'more' | 'once', number>[]

const extended2 = extender(
  [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }],
  (row) => ({ once: 1, more: row.a * 2 }),
  'once',
); // Record<'a' | 'more' | 'once', number>[]

const [
  e2o0, // Record<'a' | 'more' | 'once', number> | undefined
  e2o1, // Record<'a' | 'more' | 'once', number> | undefined
  e2o2, // Record<'a' | 'more' | 'once', number> | undefined
  e2o3, // Record<'a' | 'more' | 'once', number> | undefined
  e2o4, // Record<'a' | 'more' | 'once', number> | undefined
  // etc...
] = extended2;


// Tuple correctness:

const extended3 = extender(
  [{ a: 1, b: 1 }, { a: 2, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 3 }] as [Record<'a' | 'b', number>, Record<'a' | 'b', number>, Record<'a' | 'b', number>],
  (row) => ({ a: 'hi', once: 1, more: row.a * 2 }),
  'once',
); /* [
  { a: string } & Record<'b' | 'more' | 'once', number>,
  { a: string } & Record<'b' | 'more' | 'once', number>,
  { a: string } & Record<'b' | 'more' | 'once', number>,
] */

// Note the values at the tuple indexes are not potentially undefined:
const [
  e3o0, // { a: string } & Record<'b' | 'more' | 'once', number>
  e3o1, // { a: string } & Record<'b' | 'more' | 'once', number>
  e3o2, // { a: string } & Record<'b' | 'more' | 'once', number>
  e3o3, /* This error is expected
  ~~
  Tuple type '[...]' of length '3' has no element at index '3'.(2493) */
] = extended3;
```

Comment: appreciate for so detailed explanation!